# Indeterminable error when deploying ARM templates via Azure DevOps VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template

An ARM template is being deployed via a Azure Resource Deployment task in Azure Devops (VSTS) Release Management. All resources seem to get created successfully as far as I can see, however there are a few errors which cause the pipeline to fail.

```
2018-09-12T18:13:39.9155529Z ##[error]Details:
2018-09-12T18:13:39.9156550Z ##[error]BadRequest: {
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"Bad Request\",\"innererror\":{\"diagnosticcontext\":\"ef9a7ad4-440f-4786-b1dc-5cbfdee6a964\",\"time\":\"2018-09-12T18:05:15.9905958Z\"}}"
} undefined
```

It is difficult to see which resource in the ARM template causes this. Can anyone point out anything which might help determine the cause of the problem?

Comment: Providing your complete template will be helpful.

Comment: Its very long and needs breaking down into linked templates ultimately. Too long to send here. If you could see the whole template, what would be your thought process to identify? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Look in the activity log for the subscription, there should be more detail there...

Comment: At the resource group level, you should be able to check the deployments history

Comment: @DanCook use `Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` before the deployment. It will show you the exact place where template is errored